# UIAlertController with textfield: how dismiss keyboard works?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, uitextfielddelegate, resignfirstresponder

In my `UIViewController` subclass I created a `UIAlertController` with a `UITextField`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
...

     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "a title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
     let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .default) { alert in
          print("OK!!")
     }
     alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
     textField.placeholder = "a placeholder"
     textField.delegate = self
     }
     alertController.addAction(okAction)
     self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

...

}

extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
      func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
          return true
      }
}
```

Now, when alert is shown and I tap keyboard next/done button, the keyboard and the alert are dismissed and *OK!* is printed.

In my `textFieldShouldReturn` method there are neither `textField.resignFirstResponder()` nor alert dismiss command, so how it's possible that keyboard and alert is dismissed? How Apple achieves this behaviour? Has `textField` two delegates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to understand Apple `UIAlertController` behavior to add the same behavior in my alert custom controller that I'm implementing. With @matt's answer help, I think I figured out how `UIAlertController` works. Below my code snippet to *connect* all alert's textfields:

```
guard let last = textFields.last else {
    return
}
for i in 0 ..< textFields.count - 1 {
    textFields[i].returnKeyType = .next
    textFields[i].addTarget(textFields[i+1], action: #selector(UIResponder.becomeFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
}
last.returnKeyType = .done
last.addTarget(last, action: #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
```

In this way when I tap on keyboard next/done button and the last textfield is the first responder, keyboard is dismissed; otherwise next textfield becomes the first responder.

This [post](https://mobikul.com/useful-uitextfield-extensions/) has helped too.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you're not putting the question strongly enough. You can delete your extension and the line `textField.delegate = self`, and the alert will still dismiss when the user hits Return.

That behavior is automatic for an alert. Unless you disable the dismiss button, it is tapped for you by default when the user hits Return in the virtual keyboard.

As for the actual mechanism, it's an `editingDidEndOnExit` control event. This leaves you free to set a delegate without messing things up.

Comment: I'm implementing my custom UIAlertViewController and I would like to understand Apple controller behavior to add the same behavior in my custom controller. I would like to set a default delegate with default behavior like dismiss keyboard on tap on done button, but at the same time I want give the opportunity to set a custom delegate, like Apple does.

Comment: Well, I've told you how to do that. Give the text field an `editingDidEndOnExit` control event targeting your view controller. In it, "tap" the default button unless it is disabled. Then you will be behaving exactly like a UIAlertController, and by exactly the same mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @matt. `editingDidEndOnExit` dismisses keyboard automatically, so, if I have more textfields in my alert and the first one is the first responder, I can't figure how to pass focus to second textfield (when I tap on keyboard next button ) without dismiss keyboard, like iOS 
 `UIAlertController` does.

Comment: I solved and I posted my own answer. Thanks very much @matt.

Answer (score 1):

[As matt already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50804920/2886997), that behavior is normal for alerts including a textField.
*Once you hit the return-key on the keyboard it triggers `.editingDidEndOnExit` and that will dismiss the keyboard and the alert.*

You can prevent that behavior by just removing the target on the textField like this:

```
  textField.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .editingDidEndOnExit)
```

This will not dismiss the alert anymore once you tap the return-key on the keyboard.